# Can't print a dict: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: python, reactjs, fastapi

I've this error:

> crew.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')

From an API (I'm using FastAPI for backend) I've this return:

```
{"id":"1","name":{"first":"Sponge","last":"Bob"},"role":"Captain","active":true}
```

While printing on screen through REACT with a code like this

```
const allcrew = crewList.map((index)=>
    <li key={index.id}>{index.name.first} {index.name.last} <br /> <i>{index.role}</i></li>
);
```

it looks like "first" is undefined while it is in my model.py file

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CrewName(BaseModel):
  first: str
  last: str

class Crew(BaseModel):
id: str
name: list [CrewName] = []
role: str
active: bool
```

someone can understand the issue?
Before use the var "name" as a dict but just like a str all was working fine.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you create `crewList` and what does it contain?

Comment: you have to define crewname as list[dict] exactly like typescript (define type)

Comment: @Unreboot if you mean something like this 
`class Crew(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: list [dict] = []
    role: str
    active: bool`

    I've the same error, no changes

Comment: @fchancel: 
`function Crewing (props){
    const crewList = props.crewList;
    const allcrew = crewList.map((index)=>
        <li key={index.id}>{index.name.first} {index.name.last} <br /> <i>{index.role}</i></li>
    );

    return (
        <ul>{allcrew}</ul>
    )

}
`

Comment: And what's inside crewList ?

Comment: It contains {"id":"1","name":{"first":"Sponge","last":"Bob"},"role":"Captain","active":true}. Until I’ve added “name” as a dict all was working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the map function when it is inappropriate for the situation. Indeed, the `map()` method creates a new array with the results of the call of a given function on EACH element of the calling array. Now, you use all the results of `crewList` directly, not one by one.

Using `map` as you do, on the first pass through `map`, `index` matches `"id": "1"` so it doesn't know `name.first` since it is `undefined`. `map` processes each element separately.

So you can directly access the elements without using the `map` method.

```js
const allcrew = <li key={crewList.id}>{crewList.name.first} {crewList.name.last} <br /> <i>{crewList.role}</i></li>
);
```

However, if later you want to create several `li` elements, at this point you can use the `map` method with an array of crew on which you want to iterate. For example :

```js
const crewList = [
    {"id":"1","name":"first":"Sponge","last":"Bob"},"role":"Captain","active":true},
    {"id":"2","name":"first":"Iron","last":"Man"},"role":"Superhero","active":true}
]

const allcrew = crewList.map((index)=>
    <li key={index.id}>{index.name.first} {index.name.last} <br /> <i>{index.role}</i></li>
);
```

Comment: Hi @fchancel. Still in error. From the API I can receive an array of dics as in your second code block. Can be composed by a single object or more. so the use of .map should ok. any idea?

Comment: If the answer given is correct for the initial question, you can validate the answer to indicate that the subject has been answered.
Regarding your second question. You just have to check the return of your API, if the answer is not an array, put your return in an array, like this, map will work in all cases. `crewList = Array.isArray(apiResponse) ? apiResponse : [apiResponse];`

Comment: Bang! SOLVED. The issue was that I wasn't check the response. adding your code now everything works fine! THANKS YOU @fchancel!